# SuiteScript 2.0: How can I update the externalID through Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to create a script file on NetSuite using SuiteScript 2.0 to update the External Id of the classification records. For some reason, NetSuite updates all fields but externalId.

I want to create this script to update the externalIds because mostly of our CSV templates uses the externalIds to look for master data such as accounts and classes. The point is, NetSuite doesn't show the externalIds on the forms and all the records created via UI, has no information in this field. So the idea here is to schedule a script to fill this field automatically based on some other fields.

Here is my code

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/runtime','N/log','N/record','N/search'], function(runtime,log,record,search) {
    
    var qtyProjects=0;
    
    function execute(context) {
        try
        {
            log.debug('Script Started');
            
            /********** Update Project (Classes) External ID ***********/
            var classificationSearchObj = search.create({
                   type: "classification",
                   filters:
                   [    
                        ["externalid","is","@NONE@"]
                        
                   ],
                   columns:
                    [
                        search.createColumn({name: "name",label: "Name"}),
                        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_proj_full_name",label: "FullName"}),
                        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_proj_manager",label: "ProjectManager"}),
                        search.createColumn({name: "externalid",label: "Externalid"})
                    ]
                });
                                        
                var prj_srch = classificationSearchObj.run().each(processProject);
                    
                log.debug('Quantity of projects: ',qtyProjects);
                
                    
                
                log.debug('Script Finished');
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            log.debug('Error',e.message);
        }           
    }
    
     function processProject(result) {
        var number = result.getValue({name: "name"});
        var fullName = result.getValue({name: "custrecord_proj_full_name"});
        var externalid = result.getValue({name: "externalid"});
        
        qtyProjects++;
        
        log.debug('Update Number|Name|ExternalId: ',number + " | " + fullName + " | " + externalid);
     
     record.submitFields({
            "type":'classification',
            "id": result.id,
            "values": {
                "externalId": externalid,
                "custrecord_proj_full_name": "Test Ale 2",
            }
        });
        
        /*
        var project_id = project.save({
                                        enableSourcing: true,
                                        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                                        }); 
        */
        
        //return true;
     }
    
    
    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled the id of ExtermalId, it is without Capital 'I' as `externalid`. This should work.
As a rule of thumb native field id's don't have capital letters in it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to change to externalid and I still have the same problem. The field is not updated. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
    * @NApiVersion 2.0
    * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
    */
    define(['N/runtime','N/log','N/record','N/search'], function(runtime,log,record,search) {

    function execute(context) {
    var so = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: 12345
                });
      so.setValue('external','6789');
    so.save();
    return true;
    }       

    return {
    execute: execute
    }
    });
```

Comment: give this one a try

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loadig the record, setting the external id then saving it?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no success as well. 

project = record.load({
    type: 'classification',
    id:result.id,
    isDynamic: true                
    });
 
project.setValue('externalid',externalid);
var project_id = project.save({
      enableSourcing: true,
      ignoreMandatoryFields: true
      });

Answer (score 0):

Yes i tried loading the record and set external id , it worked for me . Please use record browser for internal id's of fields (externalid).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to load and set, but no success as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is searching for classes with no externalid and is updating the class's externalid with the empty value found in the search. It appears you are missing a lookup to get what the new externalid should be.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that SuiteScript 2 syntax does **not** work for updating `externalId`. For me, this simply doesn't do anything:

```
instance.setValue({ fieldId: 'externalid', value: 'FOO1' })
```

While using the older syntax actually **will** update `externalId`:

```
instance.setValue('externalid', 'FOO1')
```

You can run this in your browser's console while viewing a record to try it out:

```
require(['N/record'], function (record) {
  const instance = record.load({ type: 'customerpayment', id: 5000 })
  instance.setValue('externalid', 'PYMT1234')
  instance.save()
})
```